# why do my docker containers on SLES 12 take 2x memory compared to Ubuntu?

Tags: docker

I noticed that my docker containers on SLES 12 were taking approximately 2x the memory compared to identical containers on Ubuntu. Same version of docker.

For example, running selenium/hub, and not running any tests (not doing anything with the container at all), here are the docker stats after about 1 minute:

Just loading selenium/hub, and not doing anything (no tests, etc):

SLES 12:

```
CONTAINER    CPU % MEM USAGE / LIMIT   MEM %    NET I/O       BLOCK I/O     PIDS
8ce43b4e9a23 0.06% 149.1MiB / 15.6GiB  0.93%    0B / 0B       57.5MB / 0B   0
```

Ubuntu:

```
CONTAINER    CPU % MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %   NET I/O       BLOCK I/O       PIDS
05d3140608b4 0.12% 74.79 MiB / 15.67 GiB 0.47%   0 B / 648 B   0 B / 8.19 kB   26
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It's curious why you have PIDS=0 in SLES.

Answer (score 1):

What is the output of `docker info`?

On Ubuntu, the default storage driver is [aufs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/aufs-driver/) while SLES uses [devicemapper](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/device-mapper-driver/) or [btrfs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/btrfs-driver/).

Excerpts from the above links:

> Memory usage: the devicemapper uses more memory than some other
>   storage drivers. Each launched container loads one or more copies of
>   its files into memory, depending on how many blocks of the same file
>   are being modified at the same time. Due to the memory pressure, the
>   devicemapper storage driver may not be the right choice for certain
>   workloads in high-density use cases.

-

> Page caching. Btrfs does not support page cache sharing. This means
>   that each process accessing the same file copies the file into the
>   Docker hosts’s memory. As a result, the btrfs driver may not be the
>   best choice high-density use cases such as PaaS.

The supported storage drivers for SLES 12:

https://www.suse.com/documentation/sles-12/singlehtml/book_sles_docker/book_sles_docker.html#Docker_Used_Drivers

I guess you can use **overlay2** if you upgrade to SP2 with the 4.4.21 kernel.

https://www.novell.com/support/kb/doc.php?id=3594951

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using same image but getting different resource consumption metrics, I guess it is because of the different base kernels on respective Operating Systems.

How much resource your container(created by docker) consumes is dependent on it. Docker uses kernel level APIs([cgroups and namespaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cgroups)) to facilitate the isolation your program needs.